# what is the meaning of int[1] in c programming

Tags: c, linux, gcc, driver

i see some code like this in device driver for Linux

```
sizeof(t) == sizeof(t[1])
```

`t` is the type specifier, like int or char

so if i try `int a=int[1];` the a is 4

try int `a=int[2]` the a is 8

so what's the exact use of this syntax where i can find some reference for this use!
thanks

Comment: If you meant `int a=sizeof(int[1]); the a is 4`, that's giving you the size of an array of int with one element (which is generally the size of an int).

Comment: Could you provide a link or show us the code where you found this?